# Is there a way to minimize everything between two pragma marks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pragma

I don't think this one requires much sample code.  But for the sake of completeness let's say I have this code.

```
#pragma mark    Getters / Setters

- (NSMutableDictionary *)myDict
{
    if (!_myDict)
    {
        _myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return _myDict;
}
 - (NSMutableDictionary *)anotherDict
    {
        if (!_anotherDict)
        {
            _anotherDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }
        return _anotherDict;
    }

#pragma mark    Designated Initializer
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{  
   if (name)
      _name = name;

    return self;
}
```

Let's say I have numerous getters and setters here and I want to hide all of them (especially in a case like this where I'm doing simple lazy instantiation).  Is there a way to do that wholesale? Right now I'm simply compressing each method as that's all XCode seems to detect.

Comment: Don't think so, but perhaps you can approach it from the other direction: You could fold all with single keyboard command (shift-option-command-left) and then just unfold the ones you are currently working on (or unfold all when you scroll to the one you're interested in). Or, if you had code already organized in categories, you can collapse an entire category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a way to achieve it. Folding & unfolding the methods looks like an available option to me.

```
Fold                       ⌥⌘←      option+command+left
Unfold                      ⌥⌘→      option+command+right
```

Comment: I'll grumpily accept this as an answer, but wouldn't it be nice to be able to expand and contract an organized bit of code while working on different parts of an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.

You could always extract that code into a separate .m file, and #include it in the place where you want it. Then the compiler will insert the code at compile-time.

Note that when you use this technique, you do **NOT** want to add the .m file that your #including to your target.

Comment: yeah you could I suppose... but that seems super icky... It would be more Objective-C normal to add them in separate categories.. then they are complete compilation units, in your solution you would have to make sure xcode didn't add them to the target or you would get a sh!tstorm of errors that wouldn't make sense.